# How to list all vhosts on CentOS 7? (nginx)

Tags: centos, nginx

I have configured different virtual hosts on my machine. I want to ask the command which displays the list of all virtual hosts.

Comment: `apache2ctl -S`

Comment: we are using ngnix

Comment: Next time you may want to add that to the question :)  But... apparently there is no equivalent for nginx - see https://serverfault.com/questions/333440/see-all-active-virtual-hosts-in-nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -RiI server_name /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled/
```

Use this command for CentOS7.

Comment: Suggestion; form a habit of putting command options before all of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400933/how-can-i-list-all-vhosts-in-nginx its the answer:

```
grep server_name /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* -RiI
```

Comment: grep: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*: No such file or directory
Above output is coming